# Chrome extension that controls iTunes in Mac OS X

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome-extension, itunes, messaging

I'm creating an extension for Google Chrome that would start & stop playback in iTunes (native application), get info on its media library, etc. Action takes place in Mac OS X 10.9.3 Mavericks.

I have already found Chrome Runtime API, which has some native methods:

```
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(.., .., ..)
chrome.runtime.connectNative(.., ..)
```

They are described at [developer.chrome.com](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime). They allow to send some sort of 'messages' to native apps. I have successfully created a native messaging host for iTunes. First my attempt was to `connectNative()` to it, but iTunes was disconnecting instantly. Then I sent it a random message (I do it inside a background page):

```
chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage(
  host,
  {text: "foo bar"},
  function(response){
    console.log(response);
        // > Undefined
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        // > "Native host has exited."
});
```

So now I got two problems:

1. Am I on the right way? Is what I'm trying to do possible at all?
2. What exactly should be sent inside these 'messages'?

Generally, I need abilities to perform search in media library, to start playing certain song, to open a certain stream - all this triggered by different user actions on certain. Basically, I can create auxiliary cocoa app as a gate between this extension and iTunes, and it could do all the mess with iTunes perfectly, but I'm pretty sure it's an overkill and there exists some way to do everything inside the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Native messaging requires that the native executable support Chrome native messaging. Specifically:

> Chrome starts each native messaging host in a separate process and
>   communicates with it using standard input (stdin) and standard output
>   (stdout). The same format is used to send messages in both directions:
>   each message is serialized using JSON, UTF-8 encoded and is preceded
>   with 32-bit message length in native byte order.

Having done zero research on the topic, I am nonetheless certain that iTunes is not written to support Chrome native messaging (which is why it is "disconnecting instantly," as it has no idea what you're trying to do), and because you don't have the source to iTunes, you won't be able to change it.

If you knew how to manipulate iTunes using a different native executable that you'd written, then you could teach *that* executable to speak over Chrome native messaging, and thus act as a bridge translating your own music protocol to iTunes actions.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research, and read this article from a year ago talking about the possibilities of using iTunes from chrome.

[Link to the Article](http://gigaom.com/2013/06/11/rock-on-google-chrome-browser-is-gaining-access-to-itunes-music/)

Secondly, from there it referenced: Chrome media galleries API

[Link to media galleries API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/mediaGalleries)

I think the API provides enough to look up tracks.  This isn't a way to interface with iTunes, but to access your data from your library.  Not sure if you can communicate with the iTunes software from your browser (interesting idea though).